# Wordpress XMLRPC returning blank, but successful

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, xml-rpc

I'm trying to post to WordPress using curl via PHP - I'm posting using the XMLRPC built into Wordpress by default.

Posting is successful with the below code, but nothing is returned.  I need to know some information about the post, such as it's URL - I can do this if I have the 'post ID', which by looking at the xmlrpc.php file, it should return.  Below is my code for posting:

```
    function post($username, $password, $title, $content, $url, $category=array(), $keywords='', $type='Wordpress')
{
    $encoding = 'UTF-8';

    $title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);
    $keywords = htmlentities($keywords,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);

    $reqparams = array(
        'title'=>$title,
        'description'=>$content,
        'mt_allow_comments'=>0,  // 1 to allow comments
        'mt_allow_pings'=>0,  // 1 to allow trackbacks
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'mt_keywords'=>$keywords,
        'categories'=>$category
    );
    $params = array(0,$username,$password,$reqparams,true);
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('metaWeblog.newPost',$params);
    $ch = curl_init();

    $fp = fopen('/home/*/public_html/file.txt', 'w+');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($results, true).'</pre>';
    curl_close($ch);
    return $results;

}
```

The `echo '<pre>'.print_r($re...` line just shows `<pre></pre>`.  I have savd the verbose output of curl into a file, please find it below (I've starred out the URL):

```
* About to connect() to www.*******.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 87.106.55.179... * connected
* Connected to www.*******.com (87.*.*.179) port 80 (#0)
> POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.*******.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 1445
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* Operation timed out after 1000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
* Closing connection #0
```

As I said, the **CODE DOES POST, BUT NOTHING IS RETURNED**.  Sorry to be blunt, but I know this will start off a torrent of pointless answers.  So, should I be expecting a post ID to be returned, and if not, how can I easily get it returned?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sod's law.  After posting I tried changing the max timeout time: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);` to 10: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);` and I get some nice XML returned with the post ID embedded.

I haven't deleted this post as I thought it might be useful for someone.

Answer (score -2):

It will return ($results) the results as xml ... I think in your program it wont display anything in screen ( But u can see that xml data in source code of the output screen ) .. You should use xmlrpc_decode or XML parsing function to  get the data from returned XML .. In your program it will return the newly created post id.

For your program, I think folowing changes will do the work

```
$results = curl_exec($ch);
$results = xmlrpc_decode($results);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($results, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Answered ages ago, seems to be a pointless answer just to post an even more pointless link. -1